# using DependencyInjection in the Configure Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

In an ASP.NET CORE web application, I have a `MyRepository` class and an Interface `IMyRepository` that manages the access to the repository (database).

Each time a user connects to the application(on the site), I need to log an entry in the database.

In Startup.cs, in the `ConfigureServices` method I do

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adds services required for using options.
    services.AddOptions();
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

Then in the `Configure` method I need to update the database

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
// ...
IMyRepository myRep = ??? // should inject somehow
// ...

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = Configuration["...ClientId"],
    Authority = Configuration["...AADInstance"] + Configuration["...TenantId"],
    CallbackPath = Configuration["...CallbackPath"],
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTicketReceived = context =>
        {
            var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Ticket.Principal.Identity;
            if (user.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var firstName = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value;
                var lastName = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;
                var email = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
                var connectedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var userId = user.Name;   

                // 
                // HERE ADD the info in the DB via IMyRepository
                // 
                myRep.AddUserInfo(userId, firstName, lastName, email, connectedOn);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});

// ...

}
```

So my question is how/where do I inject the `IMyRepository` for use it in that `Configure` method ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify your `Configure` method to take an additional parameter `IMyRepository myRep`, it will be injected for you as long as you register it in `ConfigureServices`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
                      IMyRepository myRep) { ... }
```

Comment: yes because I think `ConfigureServices` method runs first before `Configure`

Comment: so simple?! :) what if the OnTicketsRecieved is a function defined outside the Configure method?

Comment: @SergeI I think then you have to use constructor injection and pass an instance of `IMyRepository` to your constructor . For example in controller.

Comment: humm... the problem that actually I don't know how to link the "connected event" to a controller's action... I use already constructor injection in controllers, but this time I don't know how to move that code in controller...

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped me.